How to configure SQL Server connection string utilizing docker and ngrok?
I am a student working on a MAUI app / API that needs to utilize Docker containers and ngrok. Currently, I have both my api and SQL Server in Docker containers. I am having issues when the API is trying to connect to the SQL Server container, specifically error 500.
My SQL Server is running localdb. I made sure to add an admin user with the relevant credentials/admin authentication. My Docker container are Linux-based and my computer is a Windows (the containers gave me grief and this fixed it).
I have tried using the ngrok url as a whole, part of the url, localhost, and many other combinations. I have my ngrok auth token in the ngrok.yml file and call upon the a default connection string in the launchsettings.json in my API to connect as well.
I am sure it is something quite simple but I have looked through a lot of documentation, examples, and other posts with little help. Thank you for any assistance you can provide!
docker-compose.yaml
services:
  sql-server:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    container_name: sql-server
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - ADMIN_PASSWORD=adminPassword32!
      - SQL_SERVER_URL=6.tcp.ngrok.io,18846
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"  # Exposes SQL Server port to host
    networks:
      - recipe-network

  recipe-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: RecipeAPI/Dockerfile
    container_name: recipe-api
    depends_on:
      - sql-server
    environment:
      - RECIPE_API_URL=https://3ed42d472f7e.ngrok.app
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection="Data Source=sql-server,1433;Database=RecipesDB;User ID=admin;Password=adminPassword32!;TrustServerCertificate=true;"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"  # Exposes API port to host
    networks:
      - recipe-network
    restart: on-failure

networks:
  recipe-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  android-sdk-volume:

appsettings.json within recipe-api
  "ConnectionStings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=sql-server,1433;Database=RecipesDB;User ID=admin;Password=adminPassword32!;TrustServerCertificate=true;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}


From a networking perspective Docker containers are essentially their own little Linux VMs, meaning that localhost, 127.0.0.1 and ::1 all reference the container itself. Since you don't actually have SQL Server running and listening inside the recipe-api container have you tried referencing the other container by name in the connection string, i.e.: Data Source=sql-server,1433;...?

@AlwaysLearning Thank you for the response! In the docker-compose.yaml file I did attempt to set Data Source=sql-server, 1433 but did not have any luck. I also tried setting this connection string in the appsettings.json file within the recipe-api. I added the appsettings.json file contents and updated the ngrok urls in hopes this can assist.
